# VS Code doesn't recognize pep8

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

To use linting for Python, I configured `VS Code` like this:

```
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.lintOnTextChange": true,
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true
```

Then I opened a `*.py` file and added an unnecessary space and saved, then I got an error: `Linter pep8 is not installed`.

But I already installed `pep8`. And by using VS Code console I can find the `pep8`.

#### With VS Code console

```
/usr/bin/python -m pip install pep8
loading ~/.zshrc_osx
ironsand@macbook ~ % /usr/bin/python -m pip install pep8
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
ironsand@macbook ~ % which python
/usr/bin/python
ironsand@macbook ~ % which pep8
/usr/local/bin/pep8
ironsand@macbook ~ % pep8 --version
1.7.0
ironsand@macbook ~ % which python
/usr/bin/python
ironsand@macbook ~ %
```

Maybe I installed `pep8` by using `pip2` that is installed `brew`.

#### With OS Console(iTerm2)

```
python --version
Python 2.7.10
ironsand@macbook ~ % /usr/local/bin/pip2 install pep8
Collecting pep8
  Using cached pep8-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: pep8
Successfully installed pep8-1.7.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Plugins

```
MagicPython 1.0.12
Python 0.7.0
Python for VSCode 0.2.3
```

Comment: Try installing Python for VSCode and pip install `flake8`.

Comment: I already installed `Python for VSCode`. and I installed `flake8`, but I got same error. I'll add plugins info to my question.

Answer (score 16):

PEP8 was renamed to [pycodestyle](https://pypi.org/project/pycodestyle/). In the Python VS Code Extension (by Microsoft) it is already renamed in the command palette and in the settings.json file. However the documentation for them are not up-to-date yet and they can be confusing.

Comment: On a mac, pep8 checking worked for me after I added: `"python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true` to `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Answer (score 8):

The problem with pep8 is because vscode now is using flake8, is basically the same, pep8 was renamed to pycodestyle, flake8 use pycodestyle, this is the old config:

```
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true, // Don't use it
```

But now you can't find that config in vscode, the new config line now is:

```
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true, // This is the new config for pep8
```

If the second option didn't work, you can try this:

```
"python.linting.pycodestyleEnabled": true // You need: pip install pycodestyle
```

I hope this answer is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

May sound trivial, but have you installed `Python` for vscode? The one by DonJayamanne works great.

If so, try adding your [pythonPath](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Python-Path-and-Version) to the `settings` of your vscode editor, at least, it solved the problem for me.

`pep8` path should be auto discovered then, if not, you may want to add your [pep8Path](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Linting#pep8) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, but I was having the same problem where VS Code wasn't recognizing PEP8.  An uninstall followed by a reinstall did the trick for me.