# gurobipy - No name 'GRB' in module 'gurobipy'

Tags: python, gurobi

Using Gurobi on VSCode on Windows 10.

I have the following code

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
```

Now the interesting this is that when I put this in a `.py` file, I get the error

```
No name 'GRB' in module 'gurobipy'
```

But doing the same thing a Jupyter notebook yields no error.
I installed gurobipy with pip as per the instructions here: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360044290292-Installing-Gurobi-for-Python

Further, I have the same version of Python (3.9.1) on both Jupyter Notebook and in the system (checked by running `python --version`) and `pip freeze` shows gurobipy installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a fix for it.

https://medium.com/@haominnn/how-to-deal-with-python-not-finding-tensor-flow-module-under-anaconda-3aefa8ffae11

Essentially just disable pylint and replace with pep8.

The medium link is outdated for pep8, use [VS Code doesn't recognize pep8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46011419/vs-code-doesnt-recognize-pep8) instead